# C# - Multiple generic types in one list

Tags: c#, generics

This is probably not possible, but I have this class:

```
public class Metadata<DataType> where DataType : struct
{
    private DataType mDataType;
}
```

There's more to it, but let's keep it simple.  The generic type (DataType) is limited to value types by the where statement.  What I want to do is have a list of these Metadata objects of varying types (DataType).  Such as:

```
List<Metadata> metadataObjects;
metadataObjects.Add(new Metadata<int>());
metadataObjects.Add(new Metadata<bool>());
metadataObjects.Add(new Metadata<double>());
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: I wonder if there's any real benefit to the approaches in the below answers compared to just using a `List<object>`? They won't stop boxing/unboxing, they won't remove the need for casting, and ultimately, you are getting a `Metadata` object that does not tell you anything about the actual `DataType`, I was searching for a solution to address those issues. If you're going to declare an interface/class, just for the sake of being able to put the implementing/derived generic type in a generic list, just _how different_ is that than using a `List<object>` other than having a meaningless layer?

Comment: Both the abstract base class and interface provide a degree of control by restricting the type of elements that can be added to the list. I also can't see how boxing comes into this.

Comment: Of course, if you are using .NET v4.0 or higher then covariance is the solution. `List<Metadata<object>>` does the trick.

Comment: @0b101010 I was thinking the same, but unfortunately variance is not allowed on value types. Since OP has a `struct` constraint, it doesn't work here. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051322/conversion-error-with-generic-covariance?lq=1)

Comment: @0b101010, Both only restrict reference types, any built-in value type and any struct can still be added. Also, in the end, you have a list of `MetaData` reference types instead of your original value types with no (compile time) information about the underlying value type of each element, that's _effectively_ "boxing".

Answer (score 237, accepted):

```
public abstract class Metadata
{
}

// extend abstract Metadata class
public class Metadata<DataType> : Metadata where DataType : struct
{
    private DataType mDataType;
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, but my generic class extends from another generic class, so I can't use your solution... any ideas on a fix for this situation?

Comment: Is there a benefit to this approach compared to a simple `List<object>`? please look at my comment posted under OP's question.

Comment: @leppie: Is this possible to add multiple instances of `Metadata` to the list too?

Comment: @SaebAmini Can anyone answer Saeb's question?  The object will still be boxed as `Metadata` just as it would be boxed as `object`.  I am trying to figure out why you wouldn't just use `List<object>`,

Comment: @SaebAmini A List<object> doesn't show any intent to a developer, nor does it prevent a developer from shooting themselves in the foot by erroneously adding some non-MetaData object to the list.  By using a List<MetaData> it is understood what the list should contain. Most likely MetaData will have some public properties/methods that haven't been shown in the above examples.  Accessing those through object would require a cumbersome cast.

Comment: @SaebAmini with this you can place "untyped" members into the base class and access them through the array directly. only members bound by the generic type need to be in the subclass.

Comment: @Sahuagin there are no "untyped" instances at runtime so you can't put "untyped members" into anything, not sure what you mean.

Comment: @SaebAmini sorry, by "untyped" I mean members that do not make use of the generic type parameter. anything not bound to the generic type can be pushed into the base class (or interface), and then you can use these parts of the objects without casting. you would only need to cast to make use of the generic strongly typed members. (often I put "Untyped" versions of the generic members into the base as well, which return `object` or something similar.

Comment: - Reply a correct answer to a question

- Refuses to elaborate further

- Leaves


* Insert giga chad meme *

Comment: `I am trying to figure out why you wouldn't just use List<object>`. Because it frustratingly doesn't work when T is string, datetime. You get errors it can't be assigned (without an explicit cast).

Answer (score 101):

Following leppie's answer, why not make `MetaData` an interface:

```
public interface IMetaData { }

public class Metadata<DataType> : IMetaData where DataType : struct
{
    private DataType mDataType;
}
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why this approach is better?

Comment: Because no common functionality is shared - why waste a base class on that then? An interface is sufficient

Comment: Because you can implement interfaces in struct.

Comment: Class inheritance using virtual methods, however, is roughly 1.4x faster than interface methods.  So if you plan on implementing any non-generic MetaData (virtual) methods/properties in MetaData<DataType>, choose an abstract class rather than an interface, if performance is a concern.  Otherwise, using an interface can be more flexible.

Answer (score 41):

I have also used a non-generic version, using the `new` keyword:

```
public interface IMetadata
{
    Type DataType { get; }

    object Data { get; }
}

public interface IMetadata<TData> : IMetadata
{
    new TData Data { get; }
}
```

Explicit interface implementation is used to allow both `Data` members:

```
public class Metadata<TData> : IMetadata<TData>
{
    public Metadata(TData data)
    {
       Data = data;
    }

    public Type DataType
    {
        get { return typeof(TData); }
    }

    object IMetadata.Data
    {
        get { return Data; }
    }

    public TData Data { get; private set; }
}
```

You could derive a version targeting value types:

```
public interface IValueTypeMetadata : IMetadata
{

}

public interface IValueTypeMetadata<TData> : IMetadata<TData>, IValueTypeMetadata where TData : struct
{

}

public class ValueTypeMetadata<TData> : Metadata<TData>, IValueTypeMetadata<TData> where TData : struct
{
    public ValueTypeMetadata(TData data) : base(data)
    {}
}
```

This can be extended to any kind of generic constraints.

Comment: +1 just because you are showing how to use it (`DataType` and `object Data` helped a lot)

Comment: I don't seem to be able to write for example `Deserialize<metadata.DataType>(metadata.Data);`. It tells me *cannot resolve symbol metadata*. How to retrieve the DataType to use it for a generic method?

Comment: @Cœur A little late to the party, but your question is answered in [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232535/215552). (Comment added for myself and others who get here by search).