# C# - Multiple generic types in one list II

Tags: c#, .net, types, generics

Could you please clarify for me the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list/1351071#1351071).

Why it is important that originally defined class:

```
public class Metadata<DataType> where DataType : struct 
{ 
   private DataType mDataType; 
}
```

1. is replaced with one derived from the same interface or abstract class is it maybe because IList<> members must share some common object type?
2. must that common type to have the same name as IList<> type, eg. IList -> derived from T, or IList -> derived from InterfaceT, IT?

Thanks & Regards, 
Milan.

Comment: can you please state the question directly, instead of pointing to a question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each generic type instantiation is a new type. i.e `MetaData<int>` is a different type than `MetaData<bool>`. 
The compiler generates a type like this (inspect using .Net refelector)

```
Namespace.Metadata`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

So you cannot declare a List of heterogeneous types. You can only declare a List of one type. Hence it is necessary to make all generic MetaData<> classes to be inherited from an abstract class or interface.