# Single Combined C# List with multiple class types

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, list

To build on a post I saw here:

[C# - Multiple generic types in one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)

I want to bind a WPF DataGrid to the ClassAClassBCombinedList property something like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ClassAClassBCombinedList.Data}" />
```

for the property:

```
public List<CombinedClass> ClassAClassBCombinedList
{
    get
    {
        List<CombinedClass> result = new List<CombinedClass>();
        result.Add(new CombinedClass<ClassA>(new ClassA()));
        result.Add(new CombinedClass<ClassB>(new ClassB()));
        return result;
    }
}
```

With CombinedClass defined as:

```
public interface CombinedClass { }

public class CombinedClass<T> : CombinedClass where T : class
{
    public CombinedClass(T classInstance)
    {
        Data = classInstance;
    }            
    public T Data { get; private set; }
}
```

But this doesn't work because:
*'CombinedClass' does not contain a definition for 'Data' and no extension method 'Data' accepting a first argument of type 'CombinedClass'*

You can access the Data member by casting, however this defeats the point.

```
((CombinedClass<ClassA>)ClassAClassBCombinedList.First()).Data;
```

Any ideas on how to combine a list with multiple class types and bind to them in WPF??

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not the cast. The problem is, that `ClassAClassBCombinedList` returns a `List`, whereas the property `Data` is a property of each instance in the list!

Additionally, your interface `CombinedClass` is useless, because it doesn't provide anything. You should put something like `object Data` in it and overwrite the property in `CombinedClass<T>` with the `new` keyword.

In general, I am not sure, this is a good idea to do, even though it is the accepted answer in the linked question.

Comment: Sorry my link was wrong, I've updated it. The reason I use the empty CombinedClass interface (which could just as easily be an abstract class). Is so that I can create a List of CombinedClass without specifying the class type. Doing what I'm trying to do here would be easy if both classes were derived from a base class, but they're not.

Comment: What do you mean they're not derived from a base class. According to your question they are... they derive from CombinedClass. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @SDK: Your problem is, that you are trying to bind `ClassAClassBCombinedList.Data` to the `ItemsSource` where you should only bind `ClassAClassBCombinedList`. In the DataTemplate inside your `ListView` you can access your property `Data`.

Comment: I take your point: - I'm now trying with setting DisplayMemberPath="Data" - However it's not working very well with the DataGrid as ClassA for eg contains multiple columns (Properties)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make your `ClassA` and `ClassB` use the same interface `IClass` which defines the `Data` property? Then you can make a `List<IClass>` which can contain `ClassA` as well as `ClassB` and which you can bind to your `DataGrid`.

```
public interface IClass
{
 object Data {get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : IClass
{
 // implement `Data` property
}

public class ClassB : IClass
{
 // implement `Data` property
}


{
 // make the list by adding objects of type `ClassA` or `ClassB`, don't forget to set their `Data` property
 List<IClass> result = new List<IClass>();
 result.Add(new ClassA());
 result.Add(new ClassB());
}
```

And Bind it

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = result // List<IClass>
```

Comment: This would work well, but ClassA and ClassB are already derived from different base classes, and I don't have access to change them.

Comment: Are they partial classes? if so you can make another partial with the same name that uses the interface: `public partial class ClassA : IClass {}`. After compilation the `ClassA` that you cannot change still uses the interface and my approach would work without editing the existing `ClassA`.

Comment: I'm sensing a design pattern here, but my brain doesn't allow the name of it to come up at the moment. The "two objects that you cannot change and of different types but have similarities anyway" design pattern. eerrr.... Bridge?

Answer (score 0):

You may be overthinking this.

Why don't you just create a `List<object>` and populate it with whatever objects you need to display in your UI?  Then do something like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

If `ClassA` and `ClassB` don't share common properties, you can do this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ClassA}">
         <!-- template for ClassA objects -->
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ClassB}">
         <!-- template for ClassB objects -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```