# Can I create a List<Class<T>>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class

```
public class Setting<T>
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public T value { get; set; }
}
```

now I want to create an `IList<Setting<T>>` but with different types of `Setting<T>`'s T in it, I want e.G.

```
List<Setting<T>> settingsList;
settingsList.Add(new Setting<int>());
settingsList.Add(new Setting<string>());
```

I've tried `IList<Setting<T>>` but this seems not possible since the compiler doesn't find Type `T`.

I know that I could use object but I want it to be strongly typed. So my question is if there is a possibility of getting this working.

Comment: Do you mean, for example, you have `Setting<ClassA>` and `Setting<ClassB>`, and you want to have a list that contains these two?

Comment: Related answer [C# - Multiple generic types in one list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)

Comment: @BoltClock Edited my Question to make it more clear

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generic types do not have a common type or interface amongst concrete definitions by default.

Have your `Setting<T>` class implement an interface (or derive from a common class) and create a list of that interface (or class).

```
public interface ISetting { }

public class Setting<T> : ISetting
{
    // ...
}

// example usage:
IList<ISetting> list = new List<ISetting>
{
    new Setting<int> { name = "foo", value = 2 },
    new Setting<string> { name = "bar", value "baz" },
};
```

Comment: +1 You could add `public string name { get; set; }` to `ISetting` to make it clear that the common interface can only realistically contain the operations with a common signature across all inheriting classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a common ancestor class for all the class types that you put into the list. If it should be arbitrary types you have to use `object` for `T`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `T` only inside your class:

```
class Setting<T>
{
    // T is defined here
}
```

not outside. Outside you need to specify the concrete type:

```
Settings<string> stringSettings = new Settings<string>();
```

or

```
List<Settings<string>> list = new List<Settings<string>>();
list.Add(stringSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

ye you can do it by using reflection
i wrote such code for another question but you can use this

```
public abstract class GenericAccess
{
    public static IList<T> GetObjectListFromArray<T>(T item)
    {
        var r = new List<T>();
        var obj = typeof(T).Assembly.CreateInstance(typeof(T).FullName);
        var p = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Id", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (p != null)
        {
            p.SetValue(obj, item, null);
            var m = r.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
            m.Invoke(r, new object[] { obj });
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```
    IList<int> r = GenericAccess.GetObjectListFromArray<int>(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/// <summary>
/// 消息回调委托
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">TClass</typeparam>
/// <param name="result">返回实体</param>
/// <param name="args">内容包</param>
public delegate void CallbackHandler<in T>(T result, BasicDeliverEventArgs args);

/// <summary>
/// 注册监听程序接口
/// </summary>
public interface IRegistration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 路由名称
    /// </summary>
    string ExchangeName { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 路由Key
    /// </summary>
    string RouteKey { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 回调操作
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    void Call(BasicDeliverEventArgs args);
}

/// <summary>
/// 注册监听程序
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class Registration<T> : IRegistration where T : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 路由名称
    /// </summary>
    public string ExchangeName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 路由Key
    /// </summary>
    public string RouteKey { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 消息处理器委托
    /// </summary>
    public CallbackHandler<T> Handler { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 接口回调操作
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    public void Call(BasicDeliverEventArgs args)
    {
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Body.ToArray());
        Handler?.Invoke(JsonConvertHandler.DeserializeObject<T>(message), args);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// 消息监听处理器
/// </summary>
public static class ListenerHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 单任务锁
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly object Locker = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// 所有注册列表
    /// </summary>
    public static List<IRegistration> Registrations { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 单例化
    /// </summary>
    static ListenerHandler()
    {
        List<ListenerSetting> listeners = MqNoticeHandler.Setting.GetListeners();
        MqNoticeHandler.Listener(OnMessage, listeners);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 注册监听
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="registration"></param>
    public static void Register(IRegistration registration)
    {
        lock (Locker)
            Registrations.Add(registration);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 解除注册
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="registration"></param>
    public static void UnRegister(IRegistration registration)
    {
        lock (Locker)
            Registrations.Remove(registration);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 获取监听列表
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exchangeName"></param>
    /// <param name="routeKey"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<IRegistration> GetRegistrations(string exchangeName, string routeKey)
    {
        return Registrations.Where(x => x.ExchangeName == exchangeName && x.RouteKey == routeKey);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 消息回调处理
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="consumer">消费者</param>
    /// <param name="args">消息包</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static MqAckResult OnMessage(EventingBasicConsumer consumer, BasicDeliverEventArgs args)
    {
        //Example Query and Call 
        Registrations.First().Call(args);

        //Return
        return new MqAckResult { Accept = true, ReQueue = false };
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to figure out how this answers the question, especially since you don't explain anything.

Comment: my english is very pool,sorry。

Comment: Under normal circumstances, you will use the incoming type, so you need to implement the Call method of the interface to call back to your requester. So you need to define a delegate to be passed to your requester first, and define an interface to standardize the callback operation. Implement the class to inherit the interface and implement the callback method. The above is generated by google translation