# c# class handling different data types

Tags: c#

I want to represent data of a system in the following way:

```
abstract class Param 
{
    public object value;
    private string name;

    public Param(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Param_Int : Param
{
    new public int value;

    public Param_Int(string name ) : base(name)
    {
        this.value = 1;
    }

}

class Param_Double: Param
{
    new public double value;

    public Param_Double(string name) : base(name)
    {
        this.value = 1.0;
    }

}

class Param_String : Param
{
    new public string value;

    public Param_String(string name) : base(name)
    {
        this.value = "Hello World";
    }

}
```

There are quiet some parameters involved and all of them share some common properties like some regiser id, access levels and so on and have functions like update or send to communicate over some hardware interface. I want to have stored in some list and then have access to them the following way:

```
        List<Param> lst = new List<Param>();

        Param_Int pi = new Param_Int("test int");
        pi.value = 10;
        lst.Add(pi);

        Param_Double pd = new Param_Double("test double");
        pd.value = 3.14;
        lst.Add(pd);


        foreach (Param p in lst)
        {
            // here i want to use p.value and always have to corresponding data type
        }
```

How can I achieve such behavior with C#?

Comment: Change it to a generic and you will need only one class.  Examine the NET `KeyValuePair<TK, TV>` which is quite like what you are trying to make

Comment: I'm not sure how a generic will help, has I then with every access need to specify the datatype.

Comment: @Plutonix How if he wants to have different types in the same list?

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242214/can-i-create-a-listclasst?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @w.b That would just not work. It would be possible to store different `Param<T>` in that list, yes. But you could not access the `Value` field if you looped over it... So its useless.

Comment: Have a look at `ExpandoObject` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) you can read about it on MSDN.

Comment: You need to think about your statement "// here i want to use p.value and always have to corresponding data type". What method would you call on it and how do you know that p has such a method? Same for properties. If it's something on object like ToString(), you can happily use List<Param<object>> and not care about casting. Otherwise, if they all support a common interface, you can use that. If it genuinely is an arbitrary type, you need to be delegating the thing you are doing in the list to each list even element to do.

Comment: Hey mate, do you still need a help? Did some answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need different classes for different data types. An `object` variable can hold values of any type:

```
public class Param
{
    public object Value;
    private string name;

    public Param(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var intParam = new Param("my int");
intParam.Value = 10;

var stringParam = new Param("my string");
stringParam.Value = "Hello";

var list = new List<Param>();
list.Add(intParam);
list.Add(stringParam);

foreach(var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
```

Prints

```
10 
Hello
```

Comment: Thanks, in general this would help but would require quiete some casting to calculate that would then depend again on the type.

Comment: @thefloe in what context do you want to use the values?

Comment: You shouldn't store value types as `object`s as this means unnecessary boxing

Comment: @w.b There is no way around this in this case if he wants to have different types in the same list!

Comment: @Adrian: ah now I see, this actually would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel this code, but if you don't want to change your code you can try this:

```
foreach (Param p in lst)
{
    if(p is Param_Int){
        Param_Int param_Int = p as Param_Int;
        Console.WriteLine(param_Int.value);
    } else if (p is Param_Double){
        Param_Double param_Double = p as Param_Double;
        Console.WriteLine(param_Double.value);
    } else if (p is Param_String){
        Param_String param_String = p as Param_String;
        Console.WriteLine(param_String.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For the first part, that is, having a variable type, you should look at generics:

```
abstract class Param<T> 
{
    public T value;
    private string name;

    public Param(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Param_Double: Param<double>
{
    public Param_Double(string name) : base(name)
    {
        this.value = 1.0;
    }
}
```

For the second part - identifying the type in your test; in C# 7, you can use pattern matching for this; for example:

```
foreach (Param p in lst)
{
    if (p.value is double)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to mix different types in the same list? You can't have a `List<Param< unspecified >>`

Comment: this looks interesting. How do I manage to create the list without specifying the generic type there again.

Comment: @thefloe It is just not possible

Comment: @thefloe from your example it appears that you know the type.  Although, you can just use `object` (as others have already said).  You can still use pattern matching if you do.