# Generic Method where T is List that implements interface

Tags: c#, generics

This is similar to [C# - Multiple generic types in one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)

However, I want a generic method to accept a List of objects that all implement the same interface.

This code gives the error that there is no implicit reference conversion.

```
public interface ITest { }
public class InterfaceUser : ITest { }
public class TestClass
{
    void genericMethod<T>(T myList) where T : List<ITest> { }
    void testGeneric()
    {
        genericMethod(new List<InterfaceUser>());
    }
}
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define `T` as `ITest` and take a `List<T>` as argument

```
public interface ITest { }
public class InterfaceUser : ITest { }
public class TestClass
{
    void genericMethod<T>(List<T> myList) where T : ITest { }
    void testGeneric()
    {
        this.genericMethod(new List<InterfaceUser>());
    }
}
```