# MVVM for tabcontrol based application

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

In my wpf application the main view has 5 tabs with 5 different usercontrols , since the user controls are not related to each other, I have created 5 different view models (apart from the main viewmodel).

I thought of having a List or dictionary to have the list of usercontrols and its viewmodels,
Now, I would like to bind the tabitems with the list of usercontrols and assign the datacontexts, but since the list or dictionary can be changed, I dont find a way to bind the usercontrols to the tabitems.

For example, If I have a single tab which will be associated with a usercontrol I can assign

```
 tab1View tview=new tab1View();
 tview.DataContext= new tab1ViewModel();
 tab1.Content=tview;
```

But how can I do the same from a list which has the reference of the view and viewmodels of the usercontrols?

Please teach me a best way to achieve this.

**Answer: **

> I got the answer for what I need. 
>   First, Generic type collection of the view models should be created 
>   [C# - Multiple generic types in one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)

```
public abstract class Metadata
{
}

public class Metadata<DataType> : MetaData where DataType : class
{
private DataType mDataType;
}
List<Metadata> metadataObjects;
metadataObjects.Add(new Metadata<tab1ViewModel>());
metadataObjects.Add(new Metadata<tab2ViewModel>());
```

Then create a DataTemplate selector if multiple views are to be be referenced with same viewmodel or just apply the DataTemplate

Comment: Unless `DataObject` provides a useful interface to the rest of your code, I recommend just making a list of `object`.  Your View will still be able to bind to it, and you won't have to derive from an additional class that provides no encapsulation benefit, and clutters up the code.

Comment: Use ObservableCollection, not List.

Comment: @m-y: if the list isn't changing, then List is not a bad choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this, though I'd look at using frameworks to help you with MVVM. I myself promote [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/).

**[View Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921085(v=pandp.20).aspx)**

---

**[View Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921174(v=pandp.20).aspx)**

---

**DataTemplates** - [Sample](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/)

With DataTemplates you're defining in XAML (or in code, but XAML is more likely) which view to "automagically" apply to a `ContentControl` based upon the view-model (DataContext).

Somewhere in the XAML resources:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:GeneralSettingsViewModel}">
    <View:GeneralSettingsView/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:AdvancedSettingsViewModel}">
    <View:AdvancedSettingsView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Somewhere in the XAML file that has the resources applied to it:

```
 <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelCollection}" />
```

Note: This only works if you have one view-model per DataTemplate in the scoped resource.

---

**DataTemplateSelector**

If you have a view-model that can be applied to multiple views and you determine those views through additional logic, you would want to use a `DataTemplateSelector`. Here is an example:

Somewhere in the XAML resources:

```
<!-- Possible collision because the DataType is of the same type -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="GeneralSettingsTemplate"
              DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
    <View:GeneralSettingsView/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="AdvancedSettingsTemplate"
              DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
    <View:AdvancedSettingsView/>
</DataTemplate>
<local:SettingsDataTemplateSelector x:Key="SettingsTemplateSelector"
    GeneralSettingsTemplate="{StaticResource GeneralSettingsTemplate}"
    AdvancedSettingsTemplate="{StaticResource AdvancedSettingsTemplate}" />
```

Somewhere in the XAML file that has the resources applied to it:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelCollection}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SettingsTemplateSelector}" />
```

SettingsTemplateSelector.cs:

```
public class SettingsDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate GeneralSettingsTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate AdvancedSettingsTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(Object item,
        DependencyObject container)
    {
        var vm = item as SettingsViewModel;

        if (vm == null) return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

        if (vm.IsAdvanced)
        {
            return AdvancedSettingsTemplate;
        }

        return GeneralSettingsTemplate;
    }
}
```

---

MSDN: Prism Navigation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=PandP.40).aspx
This covers Prism Regions as well as other parts of navigation.

MSND: View Discovery vs View Injection - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921075(v=pandp.20).aspx
This section covers the differences of View Discovery and View Injection and when to use each.

Comment: Hi, I implemented your example and it worked very good :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Create a collection of your viewmodels that you bind to the ItemsSource of the tab control. Then create a DataTemplateSelector to select a view for each viewmodel.

Comment: A `DataTemplateSelector` is unnecessary. You only really need this if you have a view-model that can be applied to multiple views, in which case you need additional logic to determine **which** `DataTemplate` to return, which otherwise would result in a collision. See an update to my answer showing an example of this.