# Declaring the type of a parameter from a variable of Type?

Tags: c#

How can I put the type of a variable in a method parameter as something is defined by a class variable? For example:

```
class MyClass {
   private Type _type;

   public MyClass(Type type) {
      _type = type;
   }

   public void SomeMethod(_type param) { //... }
   public _type OtherMethod() {}

}
```

So, the idea is, I could set a dynamic type to a variable in the class, and use the `Type` variable as the type for other objects.

Is it possible to do this in C#?

**Edit:**

I decided to make my question clearer and explain on why I am asking for such a feature. I have tried Generics. The problem with generics, however, is that I have to declare the type for the class every time I refer to an object of that class like: `MyClass<TSomeType> param`

In my scenario, I have a `List<MyClass> dataList` that contains `MyClass`. If I had a generic on MyClass, then dataList has to be `List<MyClass<TSomeType>>`. In this case, I am stuck because the list can only consist of `MyClass<TSomeType>`. I cannot have other kinds of Types once I declared the type for the whole class. This is the reason why I want to know if there is a more dyanmic way of declaring a Type, like I could store the type of a class to a variable, and then use this variable like a class type.

Comment: If you want to mix various generic types together, then your generic `MyClass<T>` needs to inherit/implement some non-generic interface, even if it's blank. (or optionally you can type your "dataList" as type `List<object>` then cast in/out as you access entries) You would still need to cast to/from the actual type (say `MyClass<string>`) before calling `SomeMethod` or `OtherMethod` at some point. The only other way to avoid the explicit casting in your code is to treat them as `dynamic`, or do as JonSkeet suggested to have the methods typed against `object`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this in C#?

No. What would the compiler do with a `MyClass`? It couldn't possibly know whether a method call was valid or not.

You *can* use generics instead though:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    public void SomeMethod(T param) { ... }
    public T OtherMethod() { ... }
}
```

At this point, when the compiler sees a `MyClass<string>` it knows that `SomeMethod("foo")` is valid, but `SomeMethod(10)` isn't.

If you *really* won't know the type until execution time, then you might as well just use `object`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void SomeMethod(object param) { ... }
    public object OtherMethod() { ... }
}
```

... and potentially do execution-time checking against a `Type` if you really want to.

Comment: I suspect that generics is really what xEnOn wants. But out of curiosity, would it be plausible to leverage `dynamic` for the code and use `Type.MakeGenericType` in some kind of factory to avoid much of the type checking/casting for the developers? (I suppose this just hides the type checking work into the `dynamic` part of it, but it could potentially make managing the calling code and the `MyClass` compile-time code easier to manage?)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I think it would depend on what the OP really wants to use this for, which is far from clear.

Comment: I added the reason to my question on why I wanted such a feature to clarify on why I found generic difficult to use in my situation.

Comment: @xEnOn: That doesn't help in terms of what you'd expect the compiler to do. If you want to have a mixed-type list, then clearly the compiler can't help you - so you potentially want to go for the solution at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think what yor looking for here is [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - This would give you what you are after plus the benefit of compile-time type safety.

```
public MyClass<T>
{
    public void SomeMethod(T param)
    {
        ...
    }

    public T OtherMethod()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var intClass = new MyClass<int>();
intClass.SomeMethod("10"); // would cause a compile error
intClass.SomeMethod(10); // would compile ok
string result = intClass.OtherMethod(); // would cause a compile error    
int result = intClass.OtherMethod(); // would compile ok
```

Comment: Thanks! But I found generic difficult to use in my situation. I updated my question on why I asked for such a feature.

Comment: @xenon based on your update see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)