# Get the List of max and min dates from a LIST

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting distinct Company Name through this query

```
 List<string> listCieId = new List<string>(from l in LstAdvancePaymentRep select l.CieDesc.Trim()).Distinct().ToList();
```

What i want to do is get the Minimum Dated Maximum Date for all the companies in `listCieId`

```
   List<DateTime> listCieId2 = new List<DateTime>(from l in LstAdvancePaymentRep where l.CieDesc.Trim().Distinct() select l.CtcDtStart.Value).Min().ToList();

List<DateTime> listCieId3 = new List<DateTime>(from l in LstAdvancePaymentRep where l.CieDesc.Trim().Distinct select l.CtcDtEnd.Value).Max().ToList();
```

I am new to such queries haven't used them before

**EDIT:** I am using Distinct to get a the distinct company names as there is a repetition in the LstAdvancePaymentRep

[image]

**EDIT:** Tried this out

```
 List<DateTime> lstDatesCtcStartDate = new List<DateTime>(
 from l in LstAdvancePaymentRep where l.CieDesc.Trim().Equals(lblCieName.Text.Trim()) select l.CtcDtStart.Value.Date
 );
```

How do i find the minimum date in the LIST lstDatesCtcStartDate

Comment: The problem you're running into has nothing to do with getting minimum and maximum values. It's not at all clear why you're trying to use `Distinct` in a where clause at all. Additionally, it's worth *not* using query expressions when they just add cruft, as they do in your first code snippet.

Comment: (Additionally, if you're trying to find a maximum or minimum value, why are you trying to assign the result to a `List<DateTime>`? And why are you calling the `List<T>` constructor in *any* of this code?)

Comment: I have edited my question sorry for the wrong wordings..

Comment: Fundamentally, there's enough wrong here that I don't think it would actually help you much to *just* fix this query. Instead, you should take a step back and read up on LINQ from scratch. There are plenty of tutorials and even dedicated books. It'll take you longer to get over this particular hurdle, but then you'll be in a *much* better position for the future

Comment: @JonSkeet, Hi, sorry not sure where to ask you this, can I pick your brain on something? Last night I saw [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list) that's kept my mind busy, I'd really appreciate it if you read [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list#comment18362574_353126) under the question and shared your thoughts.

Comment: Logically, it's wrong..!! because you used WHERE which is basically use for compare purpose and you used like  **l.CieDesc.Trim().Distinct()** so nothing comparison happened in that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var minDate = lstDatesCtcStartDate.Min();
```

Or, if your company object had a Name and a Date property and there where multiple of each company and you wanted a list of each distinct company with the smallest date then:

```
class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

var companies = new List<Company>();

var companiesWithMinDate = companies.GroupBy(c => c.Name).Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Date = g.Min(c => c.Date) });
```