# Multiple Struct Types in One List

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, struct, types

Is there a way to have multiple struct Types in a List using the method described for classes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)?

Refering to one answer which told to inherit from an abstract class (not possible for structs) or Interface I came up with this:

```
public interface IMemorable {}

public struct Memorable<type> : IMemorable where type : struct 
{
    private type Data;

    public Memorable<type> (type data) 
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

And Implementing the List this way:

```
List<Memorable> memorables;
memorables.Add (new Memorable<someStruct> ());
memorables.Add (new Memorable<otherStruct> (new otherStruct (6, "Six")));
```

Which should work, as it workd with classes and Structs do support inheritance of Interfaces I think?

I get this error though:

```
Assets/Test.cs(51,22): error CS0305: Using the generic type `Memorable<T>' requires `1' type argument(s)
```

In the List declaration Line

Or can you lead me to some better solution... Regarding performance, I'll probably need to store several thousands of these structs. I'm not sure if, in the case this approach will somehow work, classes inheriting from an abstract class would be better suitable...

Can you give me advice?

Comment: *why* do you want to do this? I'm sure there are other ways to address your performance concerns

Comment: Note that storing structs as an interface completely destroys any performance benefit you might be shooting for since only a reference to the boxed instance will be stored

Comment: So do you think using classes with an abstract class as the base would be better? :| I'm making a runtime test now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (with some small corrections), but it would be useless:

```
public interface IMemorable {}

public struct Memorable<T> : IMemorable where T : struct 
{
    private T Data;

    public Memorable(T data) 
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}

List<IMemorable> memorables = new List<IMemorable>();
memorables.Add(new Memorable<someStruct>(new someStruct()));
memorables.Add(new Memorable<otherStruct>(new otherStruct(6, "Six")));
```

*(Note that normally the generic types are called `TSomething` (`T` and `S` uppercase))*

Because then all you have is an `IMemorable`, that you can't use to access the `T Data`.

I will add that, in general, `struct` (and all the value types) and interfaces don't mix well, because casting a `struct` to an interface causes its boxing (and so the creation of a copy of the struct), with a single exception (that is not relevant here)

Comment: Great answer, though, why he can't access T Data? Shouldn't he be able to do `((Memorable<SomeStruct>)memorables[1]).Data`?

Comment: @Seneral your error probably appears because you are missing `public Memorable (T data)  : this()`.

Comment: @Seneral `List<Memorable> memorables;` must be `List<IMemorable> memorables`... You must have a list of **interfaces**

Comment: Updated with the error code; It's related to the List Declaration where Memorable needs a type in square brackets, which I intended to avoid using the Interface IMemorable...

Comment: @bokibeg Yes, he can access the data, but it's very difficult... he isn't using polymorphism, he has to check the type of each element, cast it to this type, and access it, so he has to duplicate the code n times, one for each struct he will use as a generic parameter.

Comment: @Seneral see my comment above, also, `List<Memorable>` should also produce an error as @xanatos suggested.

Comment: @Seneral Already responded. See the comment with **interfaces** in bold :)

Comment: Yeah read it now... Thanks, I'm getting no errors:) I think I might need to find out a way to store the type in the interface... Else I may easily do a switch regarding the type I guess, there aren't too many I paln to use

Comment: @xanatos, thanks I get it now... this probably makes the whole performance improvement idea invalid if he's accessing data too often.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you to define the type parameter `T` of your class `Memorable<T>` when using it as type parameter for the `List<>` declaration.

Generally it is not possible to declare a list that contains multiple different struct types unless you declare the list to contain any common parent types of those structs. That would be `object`, `System.ValueType` (the direct parent class of all structs) or any common declared interface.

Two generic types that only differ in their type parameter do not automatically have a common type that is more specific than any other two types with the same parent class. In other words the various `Memorable<T>` struct types with different `T` have no more derived common parent than any other two struct types. Any list that can contain both of them will also be able to contain at least any other struct type, and *only in boxed form*, i.e. as references, not values. (Which kind-of defeats the idea of declaring them as structs, unless you have other reasons as well.)

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up a lot:) I guess I have to look if I need to cast the type for every list element when I do lookup or a equality comparer; If I do, I definetely need a different solution...