# Why is this not sufficient to implement the interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to implement a "Dimension" unit which is a generic type, but which can be stored in a list alongside other Dimensions of different type.

What I want to be able to do is to store a list of these "Dimensions" in one list (so, for example, store `Dimension<int>` alongside `Dimension<string>`, in the same list), and I'd also like to be able to compare Dimensions of the same type (so, for example, compare an instance of `Dimension<string>` with another instance of `Dimension<string>`, but never compare an instance of `Dimension<int>` with an instance of `Dimension<string>`).

I've read (here: [C# - Multiple generic types in one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)) that that a (the?) way to store different generic types in one list is by using abstract classes or interfaces. This lets me achieve the first goal of storing them in one list. However, I want to iterate over the list and compare, ultimately computing the total "distance" between two different lists (with distance being defined on a per-type basis).

I'd probably get confused reading this too, so I've taken a screenshot of a really basic structure and implementation, and displaying the compile time error I am receiving.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OBQDVBj.png]

You can see roughly what I want to achieve in the bottom "Implementation" class's method - and you can also see the specific problem I'm running into while trying to implement the interface.

So I guess my questions are:

How can I get around the error I'm receiving so that implementing the interface works? Why does it require an Interface as the parameter rather than allowing an implementation of the interface?

And I guess more generally - is there a better way to achieve what I want to do? Is what I want to do achievable/does it make sense?

Comment: Paste code, not screenshots.  Preferably the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Because `Dimension<T>` is more derived than `IDimension`, for example if you had a `public class DoubleDimension : IDimension { }`, you couldn't pass it into `Dimension<T>.GetDistanceBetween`, even though the contract says you can.

Comment: Simply put: `IDimension.DistanceBetween` is meant to cope with *any* `IDimension` argument, not just the one that you happen to want to accept. What would you expect `new Dimension<int>().DistanceBetween(new SomeOtherDimensionImplementation())` to do?

Comment: @JonSkeet This actually makes the most sense in the least amount of words, thanks. I've accepted poke's answer but I'm wondering whether having overloads is how you'd do it? Is there a tidier way of doing this? Or is it just an unusual thing to want to do and you've never thought about it before?

Comment: @Hy- Since you need to have a way to work with *any* `IDimension` object anway, the best solution is to have a calculation method that only depends on the things you get from the interface. But that would be difficult in your case (but you also haven’t showed your actual implementation for `Dimension<T>` either).

Comment: @Hy-: What poke said, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is your interface and your attempted implementation:

```
interface IDimension
{
    double DistanceBetween(IDimension d);
}

public class Dimension<T> : IDimension
{
    public T Data { get; private set; }

    public Dimension(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public double DistanceBetween(Dimension<T> otherPoint)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now interfaces are *exact*, they show exactly what and how you need to implement the interface members. In this case, you absolutely need a method `DistanceBetween` that not only takes a `Dimension<T>` object, but a `IDimension` object.

The interface says that you need to be able to pass *any* `IDimension` object to that method, so just accepting *one* subtype `Dimension<T>` is not enough.

So first of all, you need to implement that method directly. You *can* however include an overload that works for the particular type `Dimension<T>` in order to provide special behavior.

```
public double DistanceBetween(IDimension otherPoint)
{
    if (otherPoint is Dimension<T>)
        return DistanceBetween((Dimension<T>)otherPoint);

    // general implementation, only using what the interface provides
    return 0;
}

public double DistanceBetween(Dimension<T> otherPoint)
{
    return otherPoint.Data - Data; // or whatever
}
```

Comment: If you do `IDimension x = new Dimension<SomeT>();` and then call `y.DistanceBetween(x)` on another Dimension object `y`, then the `IDimension` overload will be used, not the more special `Dimension<T>` overload. That’s why I added the explicit type check at the beginning of the `IDimension` overload.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation signature must match interface signature. In this case that means that function `DistanceBetween` must accept any `IDimension`, not just a specific implementation of it.

The interface promises that `DistanceBetween` will accept **any** `IDimension` as an argument. The `Dimension<T>`'s failed attempt will only accept one specific implementation of `IDimension`. To implement it properly, you must change the signature in `Dimension<T>` to `public double DistanceBetween(IDimension anyVarName)`.

Comment: Thanks Shlomo, this helped. Both your and poke's answer, and Jon Skeet's comment, helped me understand this and fix it. The reason I've accepted poke's answer is just because he wrote a little more and made it a bit clearer, but you both helped, so thanks.