# How to use a map of generic converters in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I am building a helper function to map properties of an object to an object, which knows to which UI component the property is bound and how to convert their values back and forth.

Now I need the map itself, to map property names (of type String) to their ModelFieldItems, which contain a generic converter (eg StringToBoolConverter). But due to the lack of the `<?>` Operator, I'm used to from java, I can't simply write `private Dictionary<String, ModelFieldItem> items = new Dictionary<String, ModelFieldItem<?,?>>();`
where ModelFieldItem contains the type Information and the converter itself.

As a result I need to add specific Types if I want to add a ModelFieldItem to the map, but they differ in type.
I already tried to use `dynamic` or `object` as type parameters, but sooner or later I reach a point, where it does not work.

Using the trick from [C# - Multiple generic types in one list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353134/3535608) I got the compiler happy, but I needed a typecast to access my converter logic, which led me to the following condition

```
if (item is ModelFieldItem<dynamic, dynamic>)
{
   ModelFieldItem<dynamic, dynamic> dynamicItem = (ModelFieldItem<dynamic, dynamic>)item;
```

Which always resolves to `false`.

**EDIT**

The Method, which starts the conversion, does not know, which types to convert, which is desired. We are using a loop to iterate over the properties and start their corresponding converters. So casting at the point of conversion can not be done with the distinct types, because we can not know them.

Our converters are as easy as they can be, inheriting from the following `abstract class`

```
public abstract class TypedConverter<A, B>
{
    public abstract B convertFrom(A value);

    public abstract A convertTo(B value);
}
```

---

As mentioned before, I'm from a java background, so what I want to achieve looks roughly like the following in Java

```
private Map<String, ModelFieldItem<?,?>> converters = new HashMap<>();
```

and I would use it roughly like

```
converters.put("key", new Converter<String, Boolean>());
```

How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: Are you using reflection to set the properties on the other model (via `SetValue`)? Reflection usually works with `object`s, so type safety isn't buying your anything. That said, you can use a non-generic `ModelFieldItem` with an underlying `Func<object, object>` delegate.

Comment: Also, take a look at `Convert.ChangeType` as an alternative to specifying a converter for every property -- or at least as a default implementation. You might also want to check out Automapper which specializes in mapping properties.

Comment: @TravisParks: thank you for your comments. We need the type safety in our converter to a) make the implementation clearer and b) to set the right type on the model, while through reflection we still need to set the right Type, or am I getting you wrong?.  The Idea for using delegate is nice, I will try it.

Comment: "to map properties of an object to an object" Do you `object` as type to manipulate your instances and reflection to iterate over their properties or you use your helper method directly on the property (without reflection to get the property) ?

Comment: We are using reflection through `model.GetType().GetProperty(property);`

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you encounter this type of problem, you have to use an abstraction of your class that doesn't require the generic types.

If your `ModelFieldItem` implement an interface without generic parameters, you can use it.

```
var _dict = new Dictionary<String, IModelFieldItem>()
{
    new Converter<string, bool>() // If it's implement IModelFieldItem
};

(YouWillHaveToCastUnlessYouUseDynamicType)_dict[key].Convert("true");
```

Otherwise, another way would be to replace the `ModelFieldItem` from `Dictionary<String, ModelFieldItem>` by `object` or `dynamic`, then you can cast it when accessing to the value from your dictionary.

```
var _dict = new Dictionary<String, object>()
{
    new Converter<string, bool>()
};

// You can avoid the cast too by using dynamic
// But it will cost you some perf
((Converter<string, bool>)_dict[key]).Convert("true");
```

if you know the type that you want.
You can do something like that:

```
var _dict = new Dictionary<String, object>()
{
    new Converter<string, bool>()
};

public void Convert<TToConvert, TConverted>(string key, TToConvert valueToConvert, out TConverted valueConverted)
{
    valueConverted = (T)_dict[key].Convert(valueToConvert);
}

bool value;
Convert("Key", "true", out value);
```

---

Here an other example of what you could do:

```
    public static void Convert<TToConvert, TConverted>(TToConvert valueToConvert, out TConverted valueConverted)
    {
        // You should put the dictionary outside of the method
        // To avoid to instance it, each time you call this method
        var dict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>()
        {
            { typeof(Tuple<string, int>), x => int.Parse((string)x) },
            { typeof(Tuple<string, bool>), x => bool.Parse((string)x) }
        };
        valueConverted = (TConverted)dict[typeof(Tuple<TToConvert, TConverted>)](valueToConvert);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool boolTest;
        Convert("false", out boolTest);
        Console.WriteLine(boolTest);
        int intTest;
        Convert("42", out intTest);
        Console.WriteLine(intTest);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Obvisouly, you should try if you can convert your type first and also if the conversion succeed. Finally make `Convert` return an boolean to know if it succeed or not.
But at least as you can see, there is no more `string key` required to make the conversion and it might interests you.
You also have to be sure that your variables have the right type when you pass them to the method, otherwise you will search for the wrong key.

---

Reflection solution:

With the above method you can do something like that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object[] parameters = new object[] { "false", true };
    typeof(Program).GetMethod("Convert")
    // Be sure that the types will create a valid key
        .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { parameters[0].GetType(), parameters[1].GetType() })
    // Change null to your instance
    // if you are not calling a static method
        .Invoke(null, parameters);
    // parameters[1] is an out parameter
    // then you can get its value like that
    Console.WriteLine(parameters[1]);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

With properties, that should look like this:

```
object[] parameters = new object[]
{
    propertyToRead.GetValue(objectToRead),
    propertyToSet.GetValue(objectToSet)
};

typeof(MapperObject).GetMethod("Convert")
    .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[]
        {
            propertyToRead.PropertyType,
            propertyToSet.PropertyType
        })
    .Invoke(mapperInstance, parameters);

propertyToSet.SetValue(objectToSet, parameters[1]);
```

*You may need to adjust it a bit, since I didn't try to compile it*

---

*I could give another solution, but I neither know what is your inheritance architecture nor how your `Converter` works.*

Comment: Yeah, I know. I avoid them too. But anyway, it may answer to the problem too.

Comment: @Bauss, it would be nice, if next time, you could at least let us finish writing our post entirely before downvoting it ;)

Comment: @romain-aga, I undid my earlier d/v and upvoted based on your improved answer.  Keep in mind that it's not our responsibility to wait until you're finished improving it before we pass judgement on your answer. :)

Comment: @KirkWoll, Oh. I thought it was Bauss, who d/v since he gave me some feedback about my earlier answer. Thanks for your update then ^^ I was thinking about to show in my future answers that I am still editing them, and then remove the signalment when I'm done. Because otherwise the time I write, sometimes you finish with the same answer than someone else (and there is no point to work on the "same different" answers), and like that I just inform to anyone on what I'm working on. Do you think it would be a bad idea ?

Comment: @romain-aga, it's a [well-known annoyance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303446/is-it-bad-practice-to-post-a-short-answer-first-and-then-add-details-afterwards/303630#303630) that sometimes your answer becomes obsolete before you're done.  If you look at that meta post, it goes into a lot of details.  In short -- nothing wrong with posting an anwer quickly, but IMO I'd leave off any warnings that "you're not done" and just ensure that even in its short form it's still a quality answer.

Comment: As for the reason for my original DV, I thought your interface-based solution is the canonical answer to this problem, and really don't like using `dynamic` or `object` for this sort of scenario as you end up tossing static type-safety right out the window.

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks for your feedback. I also don't like when I endup with `object` or `dynamic`. I usually use a wrapper method which specifies types or constraints in that case, to bring back the type safety. Like I did in my answer ^^

Comment: I just want to clarify I did not down vote anything. It was downvoted before I commented. I was not against the solution at all. It was a simple headsup.

Comment: @Bauss, yeah I know, sorry about that. KirkWoll did and explained himself in the comment.

Comment: @romain-aga: Thank you for your answer. Nicely done. As I pointed out in my question, I already tried using as well an ´abstract class` inheritance as `dynamic` and `object` as type parameters.  The Problem is, that the method, which does the conversion, doesn't know of the needed types, which is why I can not cast to the right type at that point. I will update my question, to better point that out.

Comment: @Phe0nix I edited my post to show you a solution with reflection that should fit better to your problem.