# Multiple classes that implement a generic interface in a single array

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Say I have a generic interface that stores a value that is typed by the generic parameter:

```
public interface IFoo<TValue>
{
    TValue SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have two classes, `StringFoo` and `DoubleFoo` whose `SomeValues` are `string`s and `double`s respectively:

```
public class StringFoo : IFoo<string>
{
    string SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class DoubleFoo : IFoo<double>
{
    double SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

I now decide that I want an array that can contain both `StringFoo`s and `DoubleFoo`s:

```
var foos = IFoo<object>[] {
    new StringFoo { SomeValue = "a value" },
    new DoubleFoo { SomeValue = 123456789 }
}
```

I would think that, since both `string` and `double` are subclasses of `object`, they would both be allowed in this array. However, I thought wrong.

So, I tried using covariance:

```
public interface IFoo<out TValue>
```

But, since the interface contains both setters and getters, I can't do this.

So, **can two classes that implement a generic interface in one array**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Multiple generic types in one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)

Comment: List<T> and T[] are completely different constructs which obviously can be converted from one to another but may display very different behavior depending on future language design decisions and their underlying runtime implementation. That's why this questions are entirely different. Fact that today answers are similar or the same does not matter from language theoretic perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved in the way Bar class is implemented (bad example provided as well). The issue is that whenever one tries to use generic interface or class implementing generic interface code may compile (providing right casts) but code will throw InvalidCastException during runtime.

```
public interface IFoo<TValue>
{
    TValue SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class StringFoo : IFoo<string>
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class DoubleFoo : IFoo<double>
{
    public double SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class Foo<TValue> : IFoo<TValue>
{
    public TValue SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Bar
{

}

public class Bar<TValue> : Bar, IFoo<TValue>
{
    public TValue SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public static class Verify
{
    public static void QuestionArray()
    {
        var foos = new IFoo<object>[]
        {
            (IFoo<object>) new StringFoo { SomeValue = "a value" },
            (IFoo<object>) new DoubleFoo { SomeValue = 123456789 }
        };
    }

    public static void BadAnswerArray()
    {
        var foo = new IFoo<object>[]
        {
            (IFoo<object>) new Foo<string>(),
            new Foo<object>(),
        };
    }

    public static void GoodAnswer()
    {
        var foo = new Bar[]
         {
            new Bar<string>(),
            new Bar<object>(),
            new Bar<double>()
         };
    }
}
```

And to verify solution one can run tests where only GoodAnswerTest will pass:

```
public class GenericsInArrayTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void QuestionArrayTest()
    {
        Verify.QuestionArray();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void BadAnswerTest()
    {
        Verify.BadAnswerArray();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GoodAnswerTest()
    {
        Verify.GoodAnswer();
    }
}
```

Comment: if there is is no use of an abstract class then we can actually not required here.

Comment: @jacek Is it possible to do it without the casting to `IFoo<object>`? The code would look cleaner without it (and be shorter to write).

Comment: @jacek Also, when I try using the casting, VS tells me "Suspicious cast: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both StringFoo and IFoo<object>"
*edit* And I just realised that `Bar` is for non-casting... Right...

Comment: @RJ if abstract class is something you would like to avoid replace it with interface - otherwise there is no way to escape from common base type

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski Got it. Thanks