# Access to generic property of inherited generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Related to: [C# - Multiple generic types in one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list) and [Access to property of inherited generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630232/access-to-generic-property-of-inherited-generic-class)

Please consider this code:

```
public abstract class Metadata
{
}

public class Metadata<T> : Metadata
{
    public List<T> MyCollection{set; get;}
}

public class MetaDataCollection
{
    public void DoSomeThing()
    {
        List<Metadata> metadataObjects = new List<Metadata>
        {
            new Metadata<int>() { MyCollection = new List<int>()},
            new Metadata<bool>() { MyCollection = new List<bool>()},
            new Metadata<double>() { MyCollection = new List<double>()},
        };

        foreach(vat item in metadataObjects)
        {
            item.MyCollection??????
        }
    }
}
```

in above code how I can access to `MyCollection` property?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to access `MyCollection` then you need to know the `T` and cast it to specific `Metadata<T>`. You cannot access it otherwise. What type would you `item` to be expected in `foreach`?

Comment: I want to check if `T` is `int` or `string` or ...

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - `item` is `Metadata` - I guess you meant to ask - what would `myCollectionItem` be IF he would enumerate `item.MyCollection`

Comment: @RandRandom Yes, thanks :)

Comment: @Arian You can safely check if `item` can actually be casted to some subtype like this: `if (item is Metadata<int> intMetadata) { intMetadata.MyCollection... }`.

Comment: How are you going to use it? Why would you need to iterate metadata of different types? It all depends on usage scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix it like `List<>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1 does it.

```
//use interfaces instead of abstract class
public interface IMetadata
{
    List<object> MyCollection { get; set; }
}

public interface IMetadata<T>
{
    List<T> MyCollection { get; set; }
}

//as List<> the List and List<> don't derive from each other but instead have a common interface the non-generic IList
public class Metadata : IMetadata
{
    public List<object> MyCollection { get; set; }
}

//implement the generic and non-generic interface
public class Metadata<T> : IMetadata<T>, IMetadata
{
    public List<T> MyCollection { get; set; }

    //hide the non-generic interface member MyCollection
    List<object> IMetadata.MyCollection { get { return this.MyCollection.Cast<object>().ToList(); } set { this.MyCollection = value.Cast<T>().ToList(); } }

}

public class MetaDataCollection
{
    public void DoSomeThing()
    {
        //make a list of IMetadata
        List<IMetadata> metadataObjects = new List<IMetadata>
        {
            new Metadata<int>() { MyCollection = new List<int>()},
            new Metadata<bool>() { MyCollection = new List<bool>()},
            new Metadata<double>() { MyCollection = new List<double>()},
        };

        foreach (var item in metadataObjects)
        {
            //item.MyCollection is now a List<object>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has this error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` from `this.MyCollection = value.Cast<object>().ToList()`

Comment: @Arian - here a dotnetfiddle - that it is working now - https://dotnetfiddle.net/iHKUJ6

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant, but you could lookup the generic type argument and cast accordingly as below.

```
public class MetaDataCollection
{
    public void DoSomeThing()
    {
        List<Metadata> metadataObjects = new List<Metadata>
        {
            new Metadata<int>() { MyCollection = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4} },
            new Metadata<bool>() { MyCollection = new List<bool>() { true, false, false} },
            new Metadata<double>() { MyCollection = new List<double>() { 1.5, 2.1 } },
        };

        Dictionary<Type, Action<Metadata>> actionLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Metadata>>()
        {
            { typeof(int), (meta) => Console.WriteLine(((Metadata<int>)meta).MyCollection[0]) },
            { typeof(bool), (meta) => Console.WriteLine(((Metadata<bool>)meta).MyCollection[0]) },
            { typeof(double), (meta) => Console.WriteLine(((Metadata<double>)meta).MyCollection[0]) }
        };

        foreach (var item in metadataObjects)
        {
            Type metaDataType = item.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First();
            actionLookup[metaDataType](item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code below breaks OOP ideology and rules, but it will achieve the aim.
And be ware of exceptions

```
        foreach(dynamic item in metadataObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.MyCollection.Count);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to the dark side of dynamic can fix everything. :)

Answer (score 0):

you must check your Item type and then cast it into a suitable MetaData:

```
public abstract class Metadata
{
}

public class Metadata<T> : Metadata
{
    public List<T> MyCollection { set; get; }
}

public class MetaDataCollection
{
    public void DoSomeThing()
    {
        List<Metadata> metadataObjects = new List<Metadata>
    {
        new Metadata<int>() { MyCollection = new List<int>()},
        new Metadata<bool>() { MyCollection = new List<bool>()},
        new Metadata<double>() { MyCollection = new List<double>()},
    };

        foreach (var item in metadataObjects)
        {
            if (item is Metadata<int>)
            {
                var intItem = item as Metadata<int>;
                intItem.Add(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you already know that it is `Metadata<int>` I would recommend make direct casting `(Metadata<int>)item`. Otherwise, it can mislead and look like `intItem` can be `null`. With C# 7.0 you can actually just combine `is` with `as`: `if (item is Metadata<int> intItem)`.

Comment: this is hard coding : `Metadata<int>`

Comment: How C# should predict your data Type ? Worst Case is to cast your object into MetaData<object> and it will cause some runtime errors !