# Placing different generic types into a data structure, and then handling them upon removal

Tags: c#, generics, data-structures, types, casting

I posted this question yesterday but it was marked as a duplicate of [C# - Multiple generic types in one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)

To clarify, the answer in that problem shows how to correctly place multiple generic types into a single list. However that's not my problem. My problem is that, upon removing items from the list, I need to know what type they are in order to handle them correctly.

As a starting point, I am using the answer to the above question because it does have a good solution for placing items of multiple types into a data structure. As you can see below, I have created an abstract base ScheduleItem class, and then an inheriting generic  ScheduleItem class. That allows me pass to in different types of generic to the same priority queue.

However when I dequeue these items, they are treated as the base class, which do not have the properties of the inheriting class that I am trying to access. Therefore trying to get any data out of them doesn't work. Even though, in the debugger, I can clearly see that the object I'm pulling out contains the data I want, I get errors trying to access it. I assume this is because when I'm dequeuing an object I don't know what generic type was associated with it, and so I get the base class, which has no properties associated.

```
public class ScheduleManager
{
    PriorityQueue<ScheduleItem> schedule = new PriorityQueue<ScheduleItem>();

    //case: adding an item with int data
    public void AddScheduleItem(int steps, string eventName, int param) {
        schedule.Enqueue(new ScheduleItem<int>(eventName, param, steps), steps);
    }

    //case: adding an item with bool data
    public void AddScheduleItem(int steps, string eventName, bool param)
        schedule.Enqueue(new ScheduleItem<bool>(eventName, param, steps), steps);
    }

    public ScheduleManager()
    {
        schedule.Enqueue(new ScheduleItem<bool>("test", true, 1), 1);
        ScheduleItem test = schedule.Dequeue();

        Debug.Log(test.ScheduledStep); //Coming up null
        Debug.Log(test.Data); //Coming up null
        test.Activate(); //Causing error
    }

    //The abstract base class
    abstract class ScheduleItem { }

    //The inheriting generic class. This is the one that actually 
    //holds data I need
    class ScheduleItem<T> : ScheduleItem where T : struct {
        public T Data { get; private set; }
        public string EventName { get; private set; }
        public int ScheduledStep { get; private set; }

        public ScheduleItem(string eventName, T data, int scheduledStep) {
            EventName = eventName;
            Data = data;
            ScheduledStep = scheduledStep;
        }

        public void Activate() {
            if(typeof(T) == typeof(int)) {
                int data = (int)Convert.ChangeType(Data, typeof(int));
                EventManager.TriggerIntEvent(EventName, data);
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
            {
                bool data = (bool)Convert.ChangeType(Data, typeof(bool));
                EventManager.TriggerBoolEvent(EventName, data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't use a generic interface and implementation for every generic type parameter? another option is to have a separate class for every type

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski could you show me (or link me to) an example of what you mean? Will this solve my problem of blindly pulling a node from the queue and being able to access its data no matter what type it is?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski A generic interface won't work, because there needs to be a collection which can take any type of schedule item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back to OOP basics.

You want `EventName` and `ScheduledStep` to be available regardless of the type of `ScheduleItem`. Therefore they need to be on the `ScheduleItem` class itself.

You also want the behaviour of each `ScheduleItem` subclass to be different, depending on the type of its data. An easy way to do this is to have a different subclass per type of data, which has a different `Activate` method.

```
public abstract class ScheduleItem
{
    public string EventName { get; }
    public int ScheduledStep { get; }

    protected ScheculeItem(string eventName, int scheduledStep)
    {
        EventName = eventName;
        ScheduledStep = scheduledStep;
    }
    public abstract void Activate();
}

public class IntScheduleItem
{
    private readonly int data;
    public IntScheduleItem(string eventName, int scheduledStep, int data)
        : base(eventName, int scheduledStep)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public override void Activate()
    {
         EventManager.TriggerIntEvent(EventName, data);
    }
}

... and so on
```

---

If the only difference between the different types of `ScheduleItem` is the `EventManager` method which is called, you could do something like this instead of having separate `IntScheduleEvent`, `BoolScheduleEvent`, etc, classes:

```
public class ScheduleItem<T> : ScheduleItem
{
    private readonly T data;
    private readonly Action<string, T> activator;

    public ScheduleItem(string eventName, int scheduledStep, int data, Action<string, T> activator)
        : base(eventName, int scheduledStep)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.activator = activator;
    }

    public override void Activate()
    {
        activator(EventName, data);
    }
}

...

public void AddScheduleItem(int steps, string eventName, int param) {
    schedule.Enqueue(new ScheduleItem<int>(eventName, steps, param, EventManager.TriggerIntEvent), steps);
}
```

---

You could even take it one step further and do away with the class hierarchy at all:

```
public class ScheduleItem
{
    public string EventName { get; }
    public int ScheduledStep { get; }
    private readonly Action activator;

    protected ScheculeItem(string eventName, int scheduledStep, Action activator)
    {
        EventName = eventName;
        ScheduledStep = scheduledStep;
        this.activator = activator;
    }
    public void Activate() => activator();
}

...

public void AddScheduleItem(int steps, string eventName, int param) {
    schedule.Enqueue(new ScheduleItem(eventName, steps, () => EventManager.TriggerIntEvent(eventName, param)), steps);
```

Comment: I have a question. In the example I gave, each activator has a separate name (TriggerIntEvent, TriggerBoolEvent, etc.). What if there is only one overloaded activator function? IE just TriggerEvent(string, bool), TriggerEvent(string, int), etc. I am testing now but I think that might cause a problem. Will I have to create separate local, private functions for each data type? IE private CallIntEvent(int data) { EventManager.TriggerEvent("test", data);  }  and then the same for bool?

Comment: @SemperCallide No difference: the right overload to call still has to be determined by the compiler, at compile-time. Yes in my first example, each data type will need its own class with its own `Activate` method, which calls the right `EventManager` method. See my next two samples for ways to reduce this boilerplate

Comment: First off, thank you for the excellent advice! I think I'd like to keep the param data as part of the ScheduleItem object if possible (as opposed to keeping it in the activator method as a param), because there are cases in which I will definitely need to traverse the PriorityQueue and remove nodes based on their data. For that reason I'm trying to implement the second of your suggestions, using the generic subclass. However I'm running into some of the same issues that I started off with. For instance, I can't access the Data property once I dequeue, because it's not part of the base class.

Comment: @SemperCallide Of course not: how will the code which traverses the queue know whether the item it's looking at has a bool parameter, or int, etc? That logic, whatever it is, needs to go inside the `ScheduleItem` itself

Comment: Alright - fair enough. One last question, if you don't mind. Let's say, during a traversal, I know what kind of data I'm looking for. IE: I want to examine all ScheduleItems of type int, and remove any whose data is below a certain value. Having that information, is there someway I can access the data of a ScheduleItem when examining it? I ask because so far in every case the code only views the item as its abstract base class, which has no accessors for the data.

Comment: @SemperCallide You could do `if (item is ScheduleItem<int> intScheduleItem) { access intScheduleItem.Data... }`. However that is often code smell. It would be better to determine *why* you're doing this, give it a name, and add a method to the abstract base class which returns a bool, e.g. `IsTooLargeToProcess` or whatever. Implement this in `IntScheduleItem`. You'll notice that I put common properties on the abstract non-generic base class, so that they *can* be viewed

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!! I've been programming a few years now but every once in a while I clearly need to review my fundamentals.